# Trouble printing a specific div

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox, printing

I am trying to print a specific div which has some checkboxes. I am checking those checkboxes through jQuery on page load with the data received from db.

The problem is when I try to print the div the checkboxes remain unchecked. I.e. the jQuery check doesn't affect the print view.

Below is my code to print div

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnPrint").click(function () {
        var contents = $("#printDiv").html();
        var frame1 = $('<iframe />');
        frame1[0].name = "frame1";
        $("body").append(frame1);
        var frameDoc = frame1[0].contentWindow ? frame1[0].contentWindow : frame1[0].contentDocument.document ? frame1[0].contentDocument.document : frame1[0].contentDocument;
        frameDoc.document.open();
        //Create a new HTML document.
        frameDoc.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
        frameDoc.document.write('</head><body>');
        //Append the external CSS file.
        frameDoc.document.write('<link href="css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
        frameDoc.document.write('<link href="css/activities_folder.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
        //Append the DIV contents.
        frameDoc.document.write(contents);
        frameDoc.document.write('</body></html>');
        frameDoc.document.close();
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.frames["frame1"].focus();
            window.frames["frame1"].print();
            frame1.remove();
        }, 500);
    });
});
```

The div to print is as below

```html
<div id="printDiv" >
  <p class="ques"><strong>1.    Parental conflict affects children in different ways. Have you observed any of these signs in your child recently? </strong></p>
  <ul class="filters">
    <li class="col-xs-12">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Increased anger issues" disabled>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
        <span>Increased anger issues</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Violent or criminal behavior" disabled>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
        <span>Violent or criminal behavior</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Depression & loneliness" disabled>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
        <span>Depression & loneliness</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Withdrawal from friends & family" disabled>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
        <span>Withdrawal from friends & family</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Poor academic performance" disabled>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
        <span>Poor academic performance</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Health problems & medical conditions" disabled>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
        <span>Health problems & medical conditions</span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="col-xs-12">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="q1" value="Low self-esteem, self-worth" disabled>
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></span>
        <span>Low self-esteem, self-worth</span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="btnPrint" value="Print" class="myPrintBtn">Print</button>
```

The jquery code to check the checkboxes is,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentAnsArray = ["Increased anger issues","Health problems & medical conditions"];

    $("input:checkbox[name=q1]").each(function(){

        for(var n=0; n < currentAnsArray.length; n++)
        {
            if($(this).val() == currentAnsArray[n])
            {
                $(this).prop('checked', true);
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT : Edited the `currentAnsArray` as said by @Ovchynnykov for more clarity on the question

Please help.. anyone???

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have problems in currentAnsArray, because everything else works good with jquery-1.11.3.min.js when I make

```
var currentAnsArray = ["Increased anger issues","Health problems & medical conditions"];
```

Instead of

```
var currentAnsArray = <?php $newArray1 = explode("|",$ans[0]); echo json_encode($newArray1); ?>;
```

Try to print currentAnsArray in log.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.. But currentAnsArray is fine... The checkboxes are getting checked fine... the problem is when i try to print that div, the print preview wont show the checks.

Comment: Now I understand, but I see them in Chrome on my Mac, may be it's different from browser to browser. You can try to replace them with pictures before printing.